Can’t run fcgiwrap and set permissions when installing bugzilla on ubuntu + nginx
I'm trying to install bugzilla on ubuntu + nginx and because I'm not a Linux expert, I encountered a problem at a certain stage.
I did everything according to the instructions, and when I try to access the site I get the following error in error.log:
connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock:", host: "..."

I found how to launch this socket, I launch it with the following command:
fcgiwrap -s unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock

the socket is started:
# ls -la /run/fcgi*
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jun 10 12:08 /run/fcgiwrap.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jun  9 19:20 /run/fcgiwrap.socket

but when I trying to open the website I get 502 error, and the error in error.log:
connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: ... , server: ..., request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock:", host: "..."

and the second problem, after rebooting the server /var/run/fcgiwrap.sock stops working, how can I prevent it from unloading after rebooting the system?


Are you sure that /var/run/fcgiwrap.sock and /run/fcgiwrap.sock are the same socket? 2. Socket must be writable for nginx' worker user which is usually www-data or nobody.


If you have installed fcgiwrap via apt on Ubuntu, the correct way to start it is with included systemd unit:
sudo systemctl enable fcgiwrap
sudo systemctl start fcgiwrap
sudo systemctl status fcgiwrap

This gurantees that fcgiwrap is started on boot with the proper UID/GID and socket ownership.

Yes, I ran these commands and it works after restarting the system. But the problem is that after restarting only “/run/fcgiwrap.socket” works, and to start “/run/fcgiwrap.sock” you again have to run the command “fcgiwrap -s unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock”

@7tunnel please edit your nginx.conf fastcgi_pass statement to reference  /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket. A complete statement should look like fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; as that's the socket name created by default systemd unit for this service on Debian.

Thanks for answers!
I found a solution on how to start a socket to make the site work:
spawn-fcgi -s /var/run/fcgiwrap.sock -M 755 -u www-data -g www-data  /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap

The only thing left. I can't figure out how to automatically start a socket after a "sudo restart". After restarting the system I have to start it again.
